# notepad++ regex: delete all tables from HTML text

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a pattern in this html text:

```
<html>
<body>

<font> .... (some data)
</font>
... (some data)

<table  class="list" border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1 rules=groups borderColor=black >
... (table data)
</table>

<font> .... (some data)
</font>
... (some data)

<table  class="list" border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1 rules=groups borderColor=black >
... (table data)
</table>

<font> .... (some data)
</font>
... (some data)

<table  class="list" border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1 rules=groups borderColor=black >
... (table data)
</table>

...

(and the pattern is repeated)

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to remove all tables (and their contents) and leave the rest. I tried with this:

**regex:**

```
(.*)(<table  class="list" border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1 rules=groups borderColor=black >)(.*)(</table>)(.*)
```

**replace**

```
   \1\5
```

But nothing happens ... How I can solve it?

Comment: You should not match everything before and after - just match the table and replace it with the empty string. No capturing needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Search` > `Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   <table.+?<\/table>
   ```
2. Replace:

   ```
   leave empty!
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression" and check ". matches newline".
4. Then press `Replace All`

Please note that this is just a quick a dirty solution. In general you shouldn't parse/edit XML files with regular expressions.

You can test it with your example at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/pN9yO2).

Answer (score 2):

Using regex replace all findings of `<table[\s\S]+?<\/table>` with empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should not use regexes for manipulating HTML, but in this limited case, you can. I can't vouch for this working in notepad++, since I don't use it, but the regex is standard.

Assumption: no nested tables, multiline patterns, reluctant quantifiers.

```
<table[^>]*>.*?</table>
```

The critical part is `.*?`. The `*?` is the reluctant (non-greedy) version of the `*`, which means that it matches as little as possible; in this case, that will be the entire contents of the table.